# Shared state between parent and children cause too much rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using React.js (react hooks) and I have the following scenario:

I have a component parent (parent.jsx) that contains a submit button, the parent component has 4 children components (child1.jsx , child2.jsx, child3.jsx and child4.jsx).

Each child of these 4 children has its own fields, and when I press the submit button in the parent all the values of these fields will be submitted to an API call.

The idea is the following: I know that I can have a state in the parent for the whole fields in the children and with callbacks I can set the state, also I know that I can use **useContext** instead, but some of the fields are input and I am setting the state with **onChnage** .. this will cause the parent to be rendered as well as the 4 children .. and this will make the input laggy for the input fields.

I read that using **useRef** and **useImperativeHandle** could solve the problem so I can expose the state of the children to the parent and on submit I can send the values, also some said that I should be careful when it comes to **useRef** and **useImperativeHandle** . others recommend to use **useContext** with **useMemo** .

So as a react (hook) beginner, I am still not able to decide which approach is better or if there is a better one, but what I know is that I need to have the separation between the four children (maybe in the future I can reuse some in other components), so is there a recommended way to get what I want?

Note: I do not want to use "onBlue" instead "onChnage" I am concerned in solving the re-rendering problem more.

**UPDATE**
Example:(with a very naive way)

The parent:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Child1 from './child1'
import Child2 from './Child2'
import Child3 from './Child3'
import Child4 from './Child4'

function App() {
  const [totalParentState, setTotalParentState] = useState({});
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child1 setTotalState={setTotalParentState} totalState={totalParentState || {}}/>
      <br/>
      <Child2 setTotalState={setTotalParentState} totalState={totalParentState  || {}}/>
      <br/>
      <Child3 setTotalState={setTotalParentState} totalState={totalParentState  || {}}/>
      <br/>
      <Child4 setTotalState={setTotalParentState} totalState={totalParentState  || {}}/>
      <br/>
      <button onClick={()=>{console.log(totalParentState || {})}}>Click me to console</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

one of the children (the rest is the same but with different Object fields value):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function Child4({setTotalState, totalState}) {
  console.log("rerendeing child 4")
  const [field1, setField1] = useState("");
  const [field2, setField2] = useState("");
  const [field3, setField3] = useState("");
  const [field4, setField4] = useState("");
  const [field5, setField5] = useState("");
  const [field6, setField6] = useState("");
  const [field7, setField7] = useState("");
  const [field8, setField8] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <input value={field1} onChange={(e) => {setField1(e.target.value); setTotalState({...totalState, child4f1:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <input value={field2} onChange={(e) => {setField2(e.target.value); setTotalState({...totalState, child4f2:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <input value={field3} onChange={(e) => {setField3(e.target.value); setTotalState({...totalState, child4f3:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <input value={field4} onChange={(e) => {setField4(e.target.value); setTotalState({...totalState, child4f4:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <br/>
      <input value={field5} onChange={(e) => {setField5(e.target.value); setTotalState({...totalState, child4f5:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <input value={field6} onChange={(e) => {setField6(e.target.value); setTotalState({...totalState, child4f6:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <input value={field7} onChange={(e) => {setField7(e.target.value); setTotalState({...totalState, child4f7:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <input value={field8} onChange={(e) => {setField8(e.target.value); setTotalState({...totalState, child4f8:e.target.value})}}></input>
    </>
  );
}

export default Child4;
```

When I change a value in one of the children I will get the console log for the child4 that it is re-rendered

UPDATE:

This is the other approach using the callback depending on Pooria Faramarzian suggestion:

parent:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Child1 from './child1'
import Child2 from './Child2'
import Child3 from './Child3'
import Child4 from './Child4'

function App() {
  const [totalParentState, setTotalParentState] = useState({});
  const [child1, setChild1] = useState({});
  const [child2, setChild2] = useState({});
  const [child3, setChild3] = useState({});
  const [child4, setChild4] = useState({});

  const child1Function = useCallback((value)=>{
    setChild1({...child1, ...value});
  },[child1])

  const child2Function = useCallback((value)=>{
    setChild2({...child2,...value})
  },[child2])

  const child3Function = useCallback((value)=>{
    setChild3({...child3,...value})
  },[child3])

  const child4Function = useCallback((value)=>{
    setChild4({...child4,...value})
  },[child4]);
  
  const setAllParent = () => {
    setTotalParentState({...totalParentState,...child1, ...child2, ...child3, ...child4});
  }

  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log(totalParentState)
  },[totalParentState]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child1 setTotalState={child1Function} />
      <br/>
      <Child2 setTotalState={child2Function} />
      <br/>
      <Child3 setTotalState={child3Function} />
      <br/>
      <Child4 setTotalState={child4Function} />
      <br/>
      <button onClick={()=>{(setAllParent())}}>Click me to console</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

one of the children:

```
import React, { useState, memo } from 'react'

function Child4({setTotalState}) {
  console.log("rerendeing child 4")
  const [field1, setField1] = useState("");
  const [field2, setField2] = useState("");
  const [field3, setField3] = useState("");
  const [field4, setField4] = useState("");
  const [field5, setField5] = useState("");
  const [field6, setField6] = useState("");
  const [field7, setField7] = useState("");
  const [field8, setField8] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <input value={field1} onChange={(e) => {setField1(e.target.value); setTotalState({ child4f1:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <input value={field2} onChange={(e) => {setField2(e.target.value); setTotalState({ child4f2:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <input value={field3} onChange={(e) => {setField3(e.target.value); setTotalState({ child4f3:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <input value={field4} onChange={(e) => {setField4(e.target.value); setTotalState({ child4f4:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <br/>
      <input value={field5} onChange={(e) => {setField5(e.target.value); setTotalState({ child4f5:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <input value={field6} onChange={(e) => {setField6(e.target.value); setTotalState({ child4f6:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <input value={field7} onChange={(e) => {setField7(e.target.value); setTotalState({ child4f7:e.target.value})}}></input>
      <input value={field8} onChange={(e) => {setField8(e.target.value); setTotalState({ child4f8:e.target.value})}}></input>
    </>
  );
}

export default memo(Child4);
```

This will only cause the child component who its fields have been changed to be rendered ..

Comment: It is unlikely someone can help you without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on @Pooria Faramarzian suggestion I tired react-hook-form

```
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";

import Child11 from './Child11'
import Child22 from './Child22'

function App() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods} > // pass all methods into the context
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Child11/>
        <Child22 />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}
```

and one of the children is like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
function Child11({setTotalState}) {
  const { register } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <>
      <input {...register("child1f1")}></input>
      <input {...register("child1f2")}></input>
      <input {...register("child1f3")}></input>
      <input {...register("child1f4")}></input>
    </>
  );
}

export default Child11;
```

and it does what I want